# QJson only saves null value in QT

Tags: json, qt, debugging, null

Im using QTCreator and I have this structure:

```
typedef struct
{
     QString i;
} stBookMark;
```

These are some of the includes:

```
...
#include <QFile>
#include <QJsonArray>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QVariantList>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QMetaType>
```

And I also added this:

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(stBookMark)
```

The problem is somewhere here:

```
stBookMark x;
x.i = "Hello";

QVariant c;
c.setValue(x);

QVariantList a;
a.append(c);
a.append(0);
a.append(-119);

qDebug()<<a;

QJsonArray list = QJsonArray::fromVariantList(a);
QJsonDocument saveDoc(list);
```

qDebug() output:
    (QVariant(stBookMark, ) ,  QVariant(int, 0) ,  QVariant(int, -119) )

And the output .json file here:

```
[
    null,
    0,
    -119
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing some of the legwork for it to export correctly.  This documentation might have the answer you are looking for.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetatype.html#details

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#setValue

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#value

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#fromValue

If you main goal is to store and retrieve the values from `JSON`, then you probably don't need to stress over `QVariant`.  Try digging into this example and see how they handle all the structs and objects by adding `read(QJsonObject)` and `write(QJsonObject)`.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcore-json-savegame-example.html

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/json.html

Hope that helps.